# How to display second item of Card Layout in Secha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, cardlayout

I have 3 card items of  card layout, If i click from the other view related to second card item, then i want to display second card item, and but could not swip front side, only swip back side with two card of 1 st and 3rd.

Here is the my code of:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
 extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
 requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
 alias: 'widget.mainmenuview',
 config: {
   layout: {
     type: 'card',
   },
   indicator: false,    
   items:[
   {
    xtype:'firstpage',
    cls: 'firstpage', 
    scrollable: false,   
   },
   {
    xtype:'secondpage',
    cls: 'secondpage',    
   },
   {
    xtype:'thirdpage',
    cls: 'thirdpage',

   },

   ]

 }//end of config
});
```

This is the my card layout. Here I want to display **secondpage** of card item. it display ok by doing this, but could not swip to previous card, which is going to back.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
     extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
     requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
     alias: 'widget.mainmenuview',
     config: {
       layout: {
         type: 'card',
       },
       indicator: false,    
       items:[
 {
        xtype:'secondpage',
        cls: 'secondpage',    
       },
       {
        xtype:'firstpage',
        cls: 'firstpage', 
        scrollable: false,   
       },

       {
        xtype:'thirdpage',
        cls: 'thirdpage',

       },

       ]

     }//end of config
    });
```

I know, In cardlayout, first card item display always first, But in my condition. Display second item(secondpage) when load **Main.js** file. and Swip both side, front side first page display and back side thirdpage display.
[image]

How to do this, please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

**Edit:**

I solve this problem but when getting second items, then why load first item then second item. it means whenever display second items, few second first itesm shows.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MenuSwipTest', {
 extend: 'Ext.carousel.Carousel',
 requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
 alias: 'widget.menuswip',
 config: {
 // activeItem: 1,
 layout: {
   type: 'fit', 
 },
 indicator: false, 
 items:[
 {
  xtype:'homepage',
  cls: 'homePage', 
    //scrollable: false,   
  },
  {
    xtype:'menupage',
    cls: 'menuPage', 
  },

  {
    xtype:'categorypage',
    cls: 'categoryPage',
  },
   ]
},
initialize : function(){ 
  console.log('launch Menu Test'); 
  this.setActiveItem(1);
 },//end of config
});
```

**I have also try activeItem:1 in config, but nothing happen any change.**

Comment: Have you tried `activeItem: 1` on the carousel config?

Comment: Please see my edit part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this property in your carousel config:

```
config: {
  // .... other config properties ...
  activeItem: 1
}
```

Comment: It is ok but when load mainmenuview then first show little second firstitems then goes to second, how to remove first item display.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this.. use [`setActiveItem();`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel-method-setActiveItem)

```
   var main = Ext.create('widget.mainmenuview');

    if(condition) {
       main.setActiveItem(1);
    }
```